# Decimal value comparison using Data Compy

Tags: python, pandas, compare, data-comparison

While comparing decimal values using data compy library , the result is showcased as if 128.12 and 128.1200 are same although they are different. My question is how can I get these values as different.

Python Version - 3.9.13
Data Compy version - 0.10.3

I tried of converting both the values as string(object) before comparison.

Comment: These two float numbers are the same value. If you convert each float number to a string then you will get the same string from each, The only way they can be different is if they are defined as strings: `"128.12"` and `"128.1200"`.

Comment: How are you using `datacompy`? It is used with pandas, pyspark, etc. please show us your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Below is the code , Even after both the values declaring as string Datacompy is not showing both values are different. 
dd1 = [Row(acct_id=10000001234, dollar_amt='12-SEP-23', name='George Maharis', val='14530.100')]
dd2 = [Row(acct_id=10000001234, dollar_amt='12-SEP-23', name='George Maharis', val='14530.1')]

col = ['acct_id','dollar_amt','name','val']
basedf = pd.DataFrame(dd1, columns=col).astype(str)
comparedf = pd.DataFrame(dd2, columns=col).astype(str)
cmp = datacompy.Compare(basedf, comparedf, join_columns=['acct_id'])
print(cmp.all_mismatch())

Comment: Can someone help me?